# measure theory , f(x)=g(x)

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose  f  and  g are bounded functions defined on a closed interval $ I \subset \mathbb{R}^{n} $ and  f(x)=g(x)  for all $ x \in \ I \setminus K $ , where K has **content zero** . Prove that $ \int_{I} f =\int_{I}g $ . $$ I knew such proof in measure theory  , but here **content=0**  is unknown to me . Can someone help me

Comment: Are you sure that it shouldn't be "measure zero"?

Comment: actuall I am not sure about the meaning of Content=0 .